# How can i take characters in a url and insert it into different variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, substring, indexof

my problem is this: I have an url, for example `"www.example.com/index.html?w=100&h=200&url=http//www.example2.com".` I need to take number 100 and number 200 and insert it into two different variables. How can i do? Thanks!

Comment: Well, is it java or Javascript?

Comment: it is Javascript!

Comment: @Francesco https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/8062856  hope this might help you

Comment: i think that would be better substring and indexOf but how can i formulate the code?